# extract text with the same name used multiple times

Tags: javascript, cypress

What i want is to check that "ZZ" is showing in the table row considering that i can have other rows with the same "ZZ" in the same cell name.

i have done this so far:

```
 cy.contains('tr', 'abc...')
            .parent()
            .within(()=> {
                cy.get('td.v-cell').should('have.text', 'ZZ')
        })
```

I am getting:
expected [ <td.v-cell>, 19 more... ] to have text ZZ, but the text was 20%20%5%0%20%-0-20%-20%-ZZ

I have this html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k224U.png

How do i verify the text even if the text can appear in other rows as well..Also if i change ZZ to 20% it should be getting error as the text is ZZ.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead if `have.text` you can use `include.text` something like:

```js
cy.get('td.v-cell').should('include.text', 'ZZ')
```

Assuming `abc` is a `td` element, you can do like this:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'abc...')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('td.v-cell').should('include.text', 'ZZ')
  })
```

Again assuming that the `tr` you want to go is the immediate next:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'abc...')
  .parent('tr')
  .next()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('td.v-cell').should('include.text', 'ZZ')
  })
```

Comment: include passes the test but it is saying :
expected [ <td.v-cell>, 19 more... ] to contain text ZZ
And when i put 20% also it passes. I dont want that..I want the code to check the ZZ for only the table with detail abc.

Comment: I got expected <td.v-cell> to contain text ZZ, but the text was ''

Comment: It is nearly impossible to debug without the HTML. Please add the exact html of the element you are working on.

Comment: ```<tr class=""><td class="date-cell" rowspan="2"><div><b>21</b><span>/10/21</span></div></td><td class="tooltip-cell" rowspan="2"><div class="tooltip"><div>abc..</div></div></td><td class="category-cell"><div class="bagde badge-to-categorize"><div class="badge-label">positive</div><i class="icon-pencil"></i></div></td><td class="amount-cell" value="1"><div class="price amount-positive">1 <span>€</span></div></td><td class="v-cell"></td><td class="action-cell" rowspan="2"><div class="actions"><div><i class="icon-pencil"></i></div></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: ```<tr><td transaction="[object Object]" rowspan="1" class="category-cell"><div class="categories"><div class="to-qualify"><div class="badge badge-generic"><span class="label">testcat</span></div></div></div></td><td class="amount-cell" value="5" rowspan="1"><div class="price amount-positive">+5 <span>€</span></div></td><td class="v-cell" transaction="[object Object]" rowspan="1"><div class="tag tag-primary">ZZ</div></td></tr>```

Comment: sorry i have to split the code since it is saying it has word limit

Comment: So on the basis of which td element you want to reach ZZ

Comment: I want to check that the td abc.. has v-cell ZZ

Comment: but the abc and zz are in two different rows like `tr`. Is this your use case ?

Comment: Yes.. The abc is in the main row and the tr zz in the sub row below it

Comment: What if i have another row with another v-cell for e.g AA for the same td, how can i do it?